# 'ffmpy' cannot find 'ffmpeg' when running in PyCharm on Mac using conda env

Tags: python, macos, ffmpeg, pycharm, conda

When I ran the following piece of code in PyCharm on MacOS Catalina within conda environment:

```
import ffmpy

ff = ffmpy.FFmpeg(
     inputs={'download/v_5c80f6ac3e28a_7BumyNgu/video.m3u8': ['-protocol_whitelist', 'crypto,file,http,https,tcp,tls']},
     outputs={'download/ffmpy_test.mp4': None}
)
print(ff.cmd)
ff.run()
```

I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myname/.conda/envs/xiaoetong/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ffmpy.py", line 95, in run
    stderr=stderr
  File "/Users/myname/.conda/envs/xiaoetong/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/Users/myname/.conda/envs/xiaoetong/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ffmpeg': 'ffmpeg'


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myname/Documents/Projects/xiaoetong/ffmpy_test.py", line 8, in <module>
    ff.run()
  File "/Users/myname/.conda/envs/xiaoetong/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ffmpy.py", line 99, in run
    raise FFExecutableNotFoundError("Executable '{0}' not found".format(self.executable))
ffmpy.FFExecutableNotFoundError: Executable 'ffmpeg' not found

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The traceback info above literally implies that either `ffmpeg` is not installed or command is not added to path. However, I did install it, and I could call `ffmpeg` command successfully in terminal. I could even run that python script without error in zsh terminal within exactly the same conda environment (and using exactly the same python interpreter).

(Some information that might be useful:

1. The same code could also be run without error within the same conda environment in PyCharm on Windows 10.
2. python==3.7.5, ffmpeg==4.2, ffmpy==0.2.2 )

This error is just so weird that I have no clue. Someone please help, I would appreciate.

Comment: Have you figured this out yet?